# Fastest way to communicate with subprocess

Tags: c++, performance, ipc, shared-memory

I have a parent process which spawns several subprocesses to do some CPU intensive work. For each batch of work, the parent needs to send several 100MB of data (as one single chunk) to the subprocess and when it is done, it must receive about the same amount of data (again as one single chunk).
The parent process and the subprocess are different applications and even different languages (Python and C++ mostly) but if I have any solution in C/C++, I could write a Python wrapper if needed.

I thought the simplest way would be to use pipes. That has many advantages, such as being mostly cross-platform, being simple, and flexible, and I can maybe even later extend my code without too much work to communicate over network.

However, now I'm profiling the whole application and I see some noticeable overhead in the communication and I wonder whether there are faster ways. Cross-platform is not really needed for my case (scientific research), it's enough if it works on Ubuntu >=12 or so (although MacOSX would also be nice). In principle, I thought that copying a big chunk of data into a pipe and reading it at the other end should not take much more time than setting up some shared memory and doing a `memcpy`. Am I wrong? Or how much performance would you expect is it worse?

The profiling itself is complicated and I don't really have reliable and exact data, only clues (because it's all a quite complicated system). I wonder where I should spent my time now. Trying to get more exact profiling data? Trying to implement some shared memory solution and see how much it improves?. Or something else? I also thought about wrapping and compiling the subprocess application in a library and linking it into the main process and thus avoiding the communication with another process - in that case I need just a `memcpy`.

There are quite a few related questions here on StackOverflow but I haven't really seen a performance comparison for different methods of communication.

Comment: Probably shared memory. If possible don't memcpy into the shared memory - put the data in the shared memory to start with.

Comment: @immibis: Considering I would still need memcpy, on both ends. How much is it faster than copying binary data over a pipe?

Comment: Instant in theory, there is no copying, the data is just there in both processes simultaneously. So how fast is not doing anything?

Comment: I don't know how fast the pipe is, though.

Comment: Are you reading aggressively from the pipe at the receiver end ? I know pipes have some limitation with how much data can be fed into it, but don't recall it now.

Comment: @Arunmu: Yes, although not sure if it's maybe too less aggressively, because it is Python doing that work at the moment.

Comment: @Albert Can you try using `splice` if unnecessary copying of the data between user and kernel space is the problem (if at all).

Comment: @Albert Also, why there is a need for parent to push that much data ? Is it because the C++ process cannot access it locally ?

Comment: @Arunmu: I did not try `splice` yet. Do you think it improves considerably over just `read`/`write`? The data is calculated on the fly by the parent process.

Comment: @Albert Yes it is efficient than read-write for large data. But you will have to measure it.

Comment: @Albert Given your stated pattern of passing data between processes, I don't see how `splice` is going to be of use in this case.  You have data in Process A and need to send it to Process B.  `splice` reads data from one file descriptor and writes it to another file descriptor - but both descriptors are for the same process.  Shared memory should be by far the fastest - it requires no copying.  You put your result data in the shared memory as you compute it.  Then post to a semaphore that it's done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so I wrote a small benchmarking tool [here](https://github.com/albertz/playground/blob/master/ipc_benchmark.py) which copies some data (~200MB) either via shared memory or via pipe, 10 times.

Results on my MacBook with MacOSX:

```
Shared memory:
   24.34 real        18.49 user         5.96 sys
Pipe: 
   36.16 real        20.45 user        17.79 sys
```

So, first we see that the shared memory is noticeably faster. Note that if I copy smaller chunks of data (~10MB), I almost don't see a difference in total time.

The second noticeable difference is the time spent in kernel. It is expected that the pipe needs more kernel time because the kernel has to handle all those reads and writes. But I would not have expected it to be that much.